# Devise issue after migrating to Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, upgrade

I'm getting this error after upgrading to Rails 4.0 from 3.2.1:

> Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'

I have this in my routes file:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations", :confirmations => "confirmations", :passwords => "passwords"}
  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/auth/:provider'  => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
    get '/users/logout' => 'users#logout'
  end
```

How do I need to write it now to make it correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict because the the `devise_for` part of the first two lines try to do the same thing (i.e. create the same devise route names, causing `new_user_session` to already be in use).

You can either:

- Remove the first line
- Make the second line   `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations", :confirmations => "confirmations", :passwords => "passwords"} do`

or

- Make the second line `devise_scope` instead of `devise_for`